# Having the error: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'array' of 'Array.Find<T>(T[],Predicate<T>)'

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

So this is a school project, and I'm trying to create a grid of sorts that can be used as a 'Track' that objects can move on.
This code is used to populate an array with the locations of 240 dots that appear on the form. This is the code:

```
public void PopulateArray()
{
    int[,] grid = new int[240,240];
    for(int i =0; i < grid.Length; i++)
    {
        string dotNo = "dot" + i;
        PictureBox dot = (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find(dotNo, true).Find();
        grid[i,0] = dot.Location.X;
        grid[0, i] = dot.Location.Y;
    }
}
```

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'array' of 'Array.Find(T[],Predicate)'

Comment: This statement is causing the issue: `(PictureBox)this.Controls.Find(dotNo, true).Find()`. What are you trying to achieve by writing this statement?

Comment: may be you need to delete the second ``Find``, [doc for second Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.array.find?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the .Find() at the end on this line:

```
PictureBox dot = (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find(dotNo, true).Find();
```

If you want to actually use that find I would add a predicate.

Here you can find more information on [Predicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.8)